# Runtime Exception in Dynamic Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to create an activity that will load different fragments dynamically. 
This is how my main activity look like

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
    public class User_details extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment_loader);
        Fragment fragment=new mail_fragment();
         FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
              getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
          fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_place, fragment);
          fragmentTransaction.commit();

}
```

I am getting the following error during run time. Please check the error [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zQ-HN4JJCuZ0NMRJw64Lhhylhd6XZr6_DidweOmM2TU/edit?usp=sharing)

The fragment look like this

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
    public class mail_fragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mail, container, false);
}}
```

The XML file of main activity(User_details) is Activity_Fragment_loader

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Ask me Later"
    android:id="@+id/but_skip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/but_skip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

The XML file of mail_fragment activity is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Enter your E-mail ID"
    android:id="@+id/mail"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="119dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
 </FrameLayout>
```

I have referred to similar questions. Most of them suggest that I place the setContentView() in User_details activity after committing the fragmenttracsaction. I have tried that but i am still getting the same error.

I would also like to add that i statically embeded the fragment in the XML file and it was working perfectly. Now when I do this pragmatically it is throwing me this error.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by the following changes.I found out the problem was due to the  used in the User_details.XML.

I changed the set of code into this

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="466dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_place"></FrameLayout>
```

This previously looked like

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_above="@+id/but_skip"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

After reading the official docs on [fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html#AddAtRuntime), I found that I needed to have a layout to dynamically change fragments rather than a 
This solved the problem and now I can switch between fragments on a button Click.

Answer (score 0):

The FragmentTransaction.add method takes the id of the viewgroup to which you are adding the fragment, not the id of the fragment.
You have two alternates, either specify the name attribute of the fragment in XML like

```
<fragment
android:name="your_package_name.mail_fragment"
android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_above="@+id/but_skip"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

and then in Java, instead of calling

```
Fragment fragment = new mail_fragment();
```

use

```
Fragment fragment = (Fragment)findViewById(R.id.fragment_place);
```

and remaining as usual.

The other alternate is to not add the fragment to the XML of Activity, but create in Java. In that case, you have to specify the ViewGroup ID in the FragmentTransaction.add() method.
Hope this helps.

Comment: As I have the said in the last few lines of my question, I have tried statically adding a fragment by including it in the XML file like you suggested. When I try to load another fragment it just lies on top of it instead of replacing it(I used fragmenttransaction.replace()).  I can't understand what you mean by the viewGroup ID thing. Can you give me an example

Comment: In your case, you have to assign an ID to the relativelayout and use this id in the FragmentTransaction.add() method. This will add the Fragment to the relative layout, which is what you desire. What you are doing is try and add a fragment to another fragment.